# terraform cdk: importing resources

Tags: terraform, azure-rm, terraform-cdk

i have most of my infrastructure build out using Terraform.
I would like to add a new resource (Azure ContainerApp Job), but try doing so with cdktf.
To do so, i would need to import the dependent resources i think:

-resource group
-azure container app environment and app environment storage
-azure container registry

I read that this is possible here:  https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/resources#how-to-import

From the code at that link, i am not sure though what 'id' means in context of azure resources.  i dont see an id for a resource group on azure portal for example.   as a simple test, i have written this simple python code:

```
rg = ResourceGroup(self, 'rg_test_id', name=self.rg_name).import_from(id=self.rg_name)
TerraformOutput(self, 'rg_id', value=rg.id)
```

But when debugging, rg is None after the first line and so the 2nd obviously fails.

any documentation or help on how this should be done would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: Id is nothing but the resource ID which is available in the Portal itself as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/h4LEA4M.png). @mike01010